# What service executes that sets up the real time clock

Tags: linux, systemd, services, time

I'm looking for the service that runs that sets up the correct time on my system.
Does anyone know what service does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that is `ntp` (the daemon named `ntpd`) for Network Time Protcol.

For example:

- [Network Time Protocol daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon) (Arch)
- [RHEL7: How to set up the NTP service.](http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-set-ntp-service/)

In Fedora, you may be looking for

```
timedatex.service
```

which is related to this package:

```
timedatex is a D-Bus service that implements the org.freedesktop.timedate1
interface. It can be used to read and set the system clock, the real-time clock
(RTC), the system timezone, and enable or disable an NTP client installed on
the system. It is a replacement for the systemd-timedated service.
```

Comment: I think timedatex (or systemd-timedated for that matter) don't actually do anything  by themselves - they act as an interface for setting the time.

Comment: OP doesn't provide clues, which is why I said "may be".